# Is there an option not to automatically all a leading underscore _ to export functions in emscripten?

Tags: c++, c, emscripten, webassembly

I'm trying to compile code from c/c++. I notice that the functions exported using emscripten are all renamed to one with a leading _ .

Both manual export with `EXPORTED_FUNCTIONS=[ ]` and  export all with `-s EXPORT_ALL=1 -s LINKABLE=1` , seem to force renaming of all functions into leading _ .

Is there an option **not** to rename export functions in emscripten? (incoming branch)

Are there any good workaround to have functions in the same names in .wasm?

Comment: Seems like a very sensible thing to ask, since `_` followed by upper case letter are reserved identifiers in C and C++ both.

Comment: @Lundin Customizable prefix would be awesome.

Comment: @EricPostpischil `clang++ -emit-llvm -S` gives me `define i32 @add(i32, i32) #0 {...`, an unmodified name. That is `clang++` in the fastcomp's build\bin folder.

Comment: It also makes sense so it doesn't overwrite any properties on the Module object.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think that is an Emscripten issue. The underscore is added to the function name by the  the C linker when the library is generated (according to the _cdecl calling convention) 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/56h2zst2.aspx